# To share a local host for go gae?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

we are two people  and i want  my friend can use my local host  but it is giving error

Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
       <customErrors mode="Off"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

needless to say
we are using python 2.7  and appcfg.py cmd to run app

Comment: That message does not come from GAE, your windows machine's port 80 is already in use by IIS. Shut down IIS and try running the GAE dev server again or run it on another port.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access your sites using local address, either use RemoteDeskTop, or remotedesktop shaing by chrome .

if your friend is in same network then he can browse your application using your LocalIp address.

```
http://192.168.10.20/YourApplication.aspx
```

If your Local Ip is not accessible in other computers of same network, then change your network to Home Network, and Add allow your IIS in Firewall.